# Load json file into dictionary in angular and iterate

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a json file with a dictionary, mapping from a string to a custom class (written in python originally). I'm trying to load this object in angular and display it:

**The custom object:**

```
export interface IFaculty {
  code: string;
  name: string;
  courses: Array<string>;
}
```

**Load object as observable (in service.ts):**

```
getFaculties(): Observable<Map<string, IFaculty>> {
  return this.http.get<Map<string, IFaculty>>('../../assets/json/faculties.json').pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError('getFaculties', new Map<string, IFaculty>())));
}
```

**subscribe and set the object in component:**

```
getFaculties(): void {
  this.facultyService.getFaculties().subscribe(dict => this.faculties = dict);
}
```

I can't iterate over a map, just the keys, so I use a helper function I found on SO:

```
getKeys(map) {
  return Array.from(map.keys());
}
```

I then want to print all of the keys in the map (in the html file):

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let fac of getKeys(faculties)">{{fac}}</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**resolved:** *However I get 10 errors that all say:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined*

I've added `*ngIf="faculties"` in the table element and now the errors are gone. However I still don't understand why I need to go over the returned object and build a new map (with `buildMap`, below), or else I get an error when trying to access the `.keys()` method of the object.

**A workaround with downsides**

In the component itself, construct a map from the returned value:

```
getFaculties_2(): void {
  this.facultyService.getFaculties_2().subscribe(dict => this.faculties_2 = 
  this.buildMap(dict));
}

buildMap(obj: object) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((map, key) => map.set(key, obj[key]), new Map());
}
```

I can't figure out why there's a difference - the object returned from the service should already be a map, but I'm unable to use it as such without manually converting it to one.

Comment: Can you put `*ngIf` on table? I think, because your `faculties` is populated later but `getKeys` is called immediately, it throws that error. So try `<table *ngIf="faculties">`

Comment: This works, in combination with turning the returned object into a map via buildMap. Thank you!

Comment: Although that still doesn't explain why I need to use buildMap, if my object returned from the service is already typed.

Comment: Edit your question (do not delete the original code) and add what you have so far. It may be because of your data.

Comment: Btw, `getKeys` method returning only `keys` and not corresponding values. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Yes, that is fine, as I only wanted to do it to test that the data was retrieved properly. I am able to do `faculties.get(value)` to access the values within.